# How can I solve TypeError in TopPlay compont in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I try to make music application by using react, redux and rapid API in that use shezam api and fetching data from it
I want to create top charts section but it gives some error

[image]

it say cannot read properties of undefined reading 'tracks'

but in code i try to do this way-

```
const {data} = useGetTopChartsQuery();
const toplays = (data['tracks'])?.slice(0, 5);
```

The purpose of doing this is the actual tracks of songs are present in the data-> tracks
[image]

If I try this way it will give this error-

```
 const toplays = data?.slice(0, 5);
```

[image]

How can I solve both problems?

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `useGetTopChartsQuery`? It looks like it's an async operation but you're not awaiting it, so that may be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occur may be if data not exited then slice operation will not work so you can change it as :

```
const toplays = data?.tracks?.slice(0, 5);
```

**OR**

```
if (data) {
  const toplays = data.tracks.slice(0, 5);
  // remaining code
}
```

and

```
const toplays = data ? data.tracks.slice(0, 5) : [];
```